# android : error in datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using this [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/using-android-date-picker/) to provide a date picker in my android app

but i am getting this error:

```
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window         -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40d42048 is not valid; is your activity running?
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3071)
05-21 10:19:08.712: E/AndroidRuntime(13265):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3021)
```

how do i resolve this error???
 Please help!!!

heres my java code:

```
public class Applicant extends ActivityGroup {

private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            break;
        }
    }    
    private void updateDisplay() {
        tv_dob.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mDay).append("-")
            .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };


ArrayList<String> city=new ArrayList<String>();

EditText applicatn_formno,fname,mname,lname,addrs1,addrs2,landmrk,
pincode,stdcode,telephone,mobile;


Button btn_next,pickDate;

Spinner spin_occupation;

TextView tv_dob,tv_applndate;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.applicant);

    spin_occupation=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_ocupa);

    tv_dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edt_dateofbirth);
    tv_applndate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.applnDate);

    pickDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pickDate);



    current_date=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    tv_applndate.setText(current_date);

    pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    updateDisplay();


    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ str_state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            if(str_permant.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
            {
                Intent activity=new Intent(v.getContext(),PermanentAddress.class);
                replaceContentView("activity", activity);
            }
            else{
                Intent activity2=new Intent(v.getContext(),Applicant2.class);
                replaceContentView("activity2", activity2);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}
xml file(this is only the relevant code for datepicker)

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pickDate"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edt_dateofbirth"
            android:background="@drawable/calendaricon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edt_dateofbirth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Date of Birth"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does this exception causes Force stop your application?? May be you have finished the activity which launched that dialog

Comment: yes and instead of a button i am using an image onclick event for the datepicker to open.

Comment: please show your code and layout xml

Comment: @shivani : hi shivani,plz share relevant part of code to get more help from us

Comment: Hi Shivani some where ur passing the getApplicationContext() instead of that please pass the Activity reference so it will works

Comment: @codingdevil no i havent used `getApplicationContext()` anywhere in my code...is it because i am using `ActivityGroup` that i am getting this error??? But i need to use it because i have a tabAcivity..

Comment: That's Why ur getting the exception you have to pass ruuning Activity reference then only this exception will not occur.

Comment: problem solved! i put getParent() and it worked!! thanks for your advice!!